# Conflict between amsbook and tocloft

Tags: incompatibility, tocloft, amsbook

I use a document class that is based on amsbook class for my thesis and at the same time I want to stylize the list of figures and tables with tocloft. But apparently these two are have conflicts. A simple code as:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}
\chapter{test}
\end{document}
```

gives such error:

```
Chapter 1
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
}
l.6 \chapter{test}
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
! Too many }'s.
\l@chapter ...nt #1}\nobreak \cftchapfillnum {#2}}
\fi
l.6 \chapter{test}
You've closed more groups than you opened.
Such booboos are generally harmless, so keep going.
[1
{/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./test.aux) )
```

The only solution I found was [here](http://compgroups.net/comp.text.tex/amsbook-and-tocloft/1923158) which doesn't work for me.
Anyone has any idea how to solve this conflict?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Sorry, but `tocloft` is definitely incompatible with `amsbook`.

Comment: Remember `amsbook` is written for preparing manuscripts for the AMS and is not meant to be modified.

Comment: depending on exactly what you want to do in your lists of figures and tables, the answer to this question may be of help. [Editing the toc page with amsbook document class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/297277/579).  there is definitely an imcompatibility between `amsbook` and `tocloft` which is not readily resolved (or even thoroughly diagnosed).  since, as has been pointed out, `amsbook` is styled for ams publications, a resolution for use with `tocloft` is not of high priority.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid `tocloft` is not compatible with the AMS classes. There is no way you can use it with `amsbook`.

Answer (score 0):

I use as well `amsbook`. Since I have a lot of figures in a lot of chapters the figure number overlaps with the figure caption. An easy solution to that was to start each caption with `\quad`.

Example:

```
\caption{\quad Negative example for question xxx}
```

This solution is not sophisticated but it works.