# Editing the toc page with amsbook document class

Tags: table-of-contents, amsbook

[image]

I'd like to change 'Contents' to say 'TABLE OF CONTENTS' in all capital letters. I would like for them to read as 'CHAPTER 1.' instead of just 'Chapter 1.'

Also, excuse me for being too needy, I'd like to have dots running from the chapter title to the page number.

I know I'm asking for a lot, but I've been covering 0 ground trying to find references on this stuff. I'm currently using the amsbook document class. I've tried to include tocloft, but the package wouldn't even let me run \tableofcontents, which leads me to believe that there is a conflict somehow.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: the ams document classes have a different approach to the toc than other classes, and "adjustment" packages such as `tocloft` are incompatible.  a working approach to changing the text of a toc entry (using `\for` and `\except` is shown in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123763/579.  the other requests are not difficult to fulfill, but i don't have access to a means of checking just now.  tomorrow ... unless someone else answers first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three simple patches:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% 'Table of contents' instead of 'Contents'
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of contents}
% Use the next line if you want capital letters
%\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase{Table of contents}}

% Uppercase 'CHAPTER' label in toc
\patchcmd{\tocchapter}{#1}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}{}

% Leader dots in toc
\makeatletter
%\renewcommand\@pnumwidth{1em} % <-- depending on the total number of pages
\patchcmd{\@tocline}
  {\hfil}
  {\leaders\hbox{\,.\,}\hfil}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

\chapter{Seminorms and the Minkowski functional}

\chapter{Convex polytopes}
\section{Convex}
\section{Polytopes}

\end{document}
```

The normal value of `\@pnumwidth` is 1.6em; reduce it as shown if you have less than 100 pages (or adjust the size to suit); in the first picture the default value is used, in the second one 1em is used.

### `\@pnumwidth` at 1.6em

[image]

### `\@pnumwidth` at 1em

[image]

Comment: This was very helpful, thankyou!